# What is Ubuntu's software raid controller partition size limitation?

Tags: server, raid, disk, disk-management

Does anyone know what the partition size limitation is for the Ubuntu software raid controller? If its 2TB, does anyone know how to increase that limitation to 3TB? This is in regards to a question I posted on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/365354/what-should-the-total-space-be-for-4-3tb-drives-in-raid10-configuration).

Thanks for your time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Every filesystem has limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits), and ext2/ext3 were limited to 2 TiB, but ext4 has a much higher limit (that you won't reach anytime soon). So, use ext4 and you should be safe...

For NFS shares I think it depends on the NFS daemon/version you use (check the manuals first) and some certainly have a filesize limit. For Samba it shouldn't be a problem, except with older versions of Windows maybe?

[ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6445/can-i-create-a-4tb-raid-10-volume)

Comment: yeah the drives were partitioned as ext4. But when I setup the RAID10, mdadm only has 4TB in the RAID, when it should really have 6TB.

Comment: I see another question in reference to that which you asked.

Comment: ext[23] were not limited to 2TB, they handle 16 TB, just like ext4 ( until ext4 64bit support lands ).

Answer (score 0):

It has no practical limit.  If you use msdos partition tables though, those are limited to 2TB.  You can get around that by switching to GPT instead.